# 'System.Linq.IQueryable<NewsSite.Models.Domain.Tbl_News>' does not contain a definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I Create A News Site With MVC5 But I Have Problem .

in Model i Create A Repository Folder And in this i Create Rep_Setting for

Connect to Tbl_Setting in DataBase .

```
public class Rep_Setting
{
    DataBase db = new DataBase();
    public Tbl_Setting Tools()
    {
        try
        {
            var qGetSetting = (from a in db.Tbl_Setting
                               select a).FirstOrDefault();
            return qGetSetting;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And i Create a Rep_News for Main Page .

```
    DataBase db = new DataBase();
    Rep_Setting RSetting = new Rep_Setting();

    public List<Tbl_News> GetNews()
    {
        try
        {
            List<Tbl_News> qGetNews = (from a in db.Tbl_News
                                       where a.Type.Equals("News")
                                       select a).OrderByDescending(s => s.ID).Skip(0).Take(RSetting.Tools().CountNewsInPage).ToList();
            return qGetNews;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return null;
        }
    }
```

But This Code Have Error to Me

```
OrderByDescending(s=>s.ID).Skip(0).Take(RSetting.Tools().CountNewsInPage).ToList();
```

Error :

```
  Error 18  'System.Linq.IQueryable<NewsSite.Models.Domain.Tbl_News>' does 

not contain a definition for 'Take' and the best extension method overload 

'System.Linq.Queryable.Take<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, int)' has 

some invalid arguments  

E:\MyProject\NewsSite\NewsSite\Models\Repository\Rep_News.cs    50  52  NewsSite
```

How i Resolve it ?

Comment: You wont be able to use `RSetting.Tools().CountNewsInPage` inside your query. You have not indicated what that returns, but assuming its a valid `int`, use `int take = RSetting.Tools().CountNewsInPage;` before the quesry, and the in the query use `.....Skip(0).Take(take).ToList();`

Comment: Show Me This Error 'Error 14 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'NewsSite.Models.Repository.Rep_News.RSetting' E:\MyProject\NewsSite\NewsSite\Models\Repository\Rep_News.cs 13 20 NewsSite
'

Comment: Put `Rep_Setting RSetting = new Rep_Setting();` inside the `public List<Tbl_News> GetNews()` method

Comment: But before you do that, just use `.....Skip(0).Take(2).ToList();` to confirm the rest of your query is correct.

Comment: "Put Rep_Setting RSetting = new Rep_Setting(); inside the public List<Tbl_News> GetNews() method"   its Not Work .

".....Skip(0).Take(2).ToList(); "  Its Work

Comment: Then `Setting.Tools().CountNewsInPage` does not return an `int`. You have not shown the relevant code so we cannot guess what it is.

Comment: ' CountNewsInPage ' is int

Comment: If `int take = new Rep_Setting().Tools().CountNewsInPage;` is not working, then clearly its not.

Comment: No Again . its not Work

Comment: This code . Have error to me

Comment: i Put code and Error  . No need To Guess . 

Thank you for taking the time to my question .

Comment: Using `int take = new Rep_Setting().Tools().CountNewsInPage;` does **not** cause the error you have stated in the question!

Comment: 'Error 14 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) E:\MyProject\NewsSite\NewsSite\Models\Repository\Rep_News.cs 13 20 NewsSite
'  *************** Show  This Error .

Comment: Pic Error    http://s6.picofile.com/file/8260072476/Untitled.png

Comment: As I previously noted many times, `CountNewsInPage` is not `int`! (its `Nullable<int>`) so therefore you must use `int take = new Rep_Setting().Tools().CountNewsInPage.Value;`

Comment: My DataBase http://s6.picofile.com/file/8260072618/Untitled.png

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. The property in your model is `int?` (nullable), not `int`

Comment: This error will drive me crazy . it is int . i swear

Comment: @Kianoush go to the `Tbl_Setting` antity model, what does the entity model say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way. The plan of debugging is to split your execution, this also makes for a more reusable method in many cases. And a good idea is to avoid using null and nullables if you can, if you use them "on purpose" the you must have a plan for them.

```
DataBase db = new DataBase();
Rep_Setting RSetting = new Rep_Setting();


public List<Tbl_News> GetNews()
{
    int skip = 0;
    Tbl_Setting tools = RSetting.Tools();
    if(tools == null){ throw new Exception("Found no rows in the database table Tbl_Setting"); }
    int? take = tools.CountNewsInPage;//Nullable
    if(!take.HasValue)
    {
        // Do you want to do something if its null maybe set it to 0 and not null
        take = 0;
    }
    string typeStr = "News";

    List<Tbl_News> qGetNews = (from a in db.Tbl_News
                              where a.Type.Equals(typeStr)
                              select a).OrderByDescending(s => s.ID).Skip(skip).Take(take.Value);
    return qGetNews.ToList();        
}
```

if `qGetNews` is a empty list you now don't break everything after trying to iterate on it, like your return `null` would. instead if returning `null` for a lit return a `new List<>()` instead, gives you a more resilient result.

So I said reusable method, its more like a single action. So you work it around to this. Now you have something really reusable.

```
public List<Tbl_News> GetNews(string typeStr, int take, int skip = 0)
{
    List<Tbl_News> qGetNews = (from a in db.Tbl_News
                              where a.Type.Equals(typeStr)
                              select a).OrderByDescending(s => s.ID).Skip(skip).Take(take);
    return qGetNews.ToList();        
}
```

Infact you shjould always try to avoid returning null if you can.

```
public class Rep_Setting
{
    DataBase db = new DataBase();
    public Tbl_Setting Tools()
    {
        var qGetSetting = (from a in db.Tbl_Setting
                          select a).FirstOrDefault();
        if(qGetSetting == null){ throw new Exception("Found no rows in the database table Tbl_Setting"); }
        return qGetSetting;
    }
}
```